# Internal mic not working on Aspire One D255

Tags: 11.10, sound, microphone

I can't get my internal mic to work with any app other than Sound Recorder. I've scoured the other posts on this topic and none seem to have an answer. I've installed Alsa Mixer, Pulse Audio controls, tried minimising one of the stereo channels but nothing works. The mic is not muted. There is no function key on the keyboard to mute the mic either. The only connector options are analogue mic or analgue input. Neither do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. Worked for me.
http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11385053&postcount=15

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I've same problem. My AOD255 sound stop working after skype installed. I'm using xubuntu 11.10 64bit, since skype using some i386 libraries, so I need to re-install oss-compat. Try this steps maybe work for you

1. remove xfce4-mixer

   > sudo apt-get remove xfce4-mixer
2. remove all alsa

   > sudo apt-get remove alsa*
3. restart your laptop

   > sudo reboot
4. re-install alsa-base, apmd, alsa-oss, oss-compat

   > sudo apt-get instal alsa-base apmd alsa-oss oss-compat
5. re-install xfce4-mixer

   > sudo apt-get install xfce4-mixer

Answer (score 0):

I lost hours on this too.
In the end the best solution was to buy a relative cheap external soundcard with a jack input.

Comment: @Thomson Dawes. I think it does. My mic didn't work. After hours of reading & frustration the only solution was to buy external USB sound card with headphone output and mic input jack. The mic then worked through that. I can now use a microphone with my Ubuntu system.